How can I find the correlation of items sold in Excel?
I have a data set of sales of a supermarket. The first column is the ticket number, the second column is the code of the item sold and the third column is the name of the item. How can I calculate the correlation of the items. For example, if I sell a cup of coffee, 60% of the time in the same ticket will be a cookie present.

I tried the CORREL function in excel, but only works for numerical data.

=MATCH(itemcolumn,itemcolumn,0) will create a numerical representation.

if I sell a cup of coffee, 60% of the time in the same ticket will be a cookie present. Can you give more details about this? I can't see cup of coffee or cookie present in your data example so i cannot figure out how you get 60%

Data analysis add-in and use the correlation after formatting your data where the items are the individual fields to see the correlations between items as 1 or 0 whether it's ordered or not. But what you're really describing seems like a regression model, to predict from an input an expected outcome.

On the second ticket there are 3 orange juices - is that one purchase or 3 for the purposes of correlation?

@TimWilliams, in the image doesn't appear, but after the orange juice is extra text that says the size of the item. For example Orange Juice "Small". The 3 items of orange juice are different sizes.

So maybe gives us some actual data we could use to test with?

@ByronHernandez After reading carefully your question several times I think what you need is association rules. That's the only math concept i can relate to your example if I sell a cup of coffee, 60% of the time in the same ticket will be a cookie present. Association rules allow to get most frequent items and kind of predict that if a user buys a cookie, probbally 60% of the times user will buy a coffee too. If this is what you want, there is no relation at all with the math concept of correlation

You can try this out.  I used the code below to generate (see GenData) some dummy data, and summarized it using ComparePurchases.
In the output table on the right, the left-most "Totals" lists the number of baskets in which any given product occurred.  Values in the main part of the output are the "% co-occurrence" of other items with each product. [100 * (Number of times B was purchased with A, divided by total number of A purchases)]
I'm only considering unique purchases per basket, so not accounting for any different quantities if items.  If you need that then you'll need to explain exactly how that should work.
(updated with refactored/faster approach)
Option Explicit

Sub ComparePurchases()
    
    Dim data, ws As Worksheet, dictUniqueProd As Object, dictBaskets As Object
    Dim n As Long, cTL As Range, ub As Long, lb As Long, t, b, i As Long, i2 As Long
    Dim arr, prodNum As Long, prodNum2 As Long, results(), prodCount As Long, prodCounts(), tot As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet      'for example
    Set cTL = ws.Range("F3")  'the "Product" cell in the output table
    
    'read in all of the sales data
    data = ws.Range("A2:B" & ws.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row).Value
    Set dictBaskets = GetDict()       'for tracking unique tickets+associated products
    Set dictUniqueProd = GetDict() 'for tracking unique products
    
    t = Timer
    ProcessData data, dictBaskets, dictUniqueProd 'populate these 2 dicts from `data`
    prodCount = dictUniqueProd.count
    Debug.Print "Processed data", Timer - t
    
    ReDim results(1 To prodCount, 1 To prodCount) 'for the co-occurence data
    ReDim prodCounts(1 To prodCount)              'for per-product total count
    
    For Each b In dictBaskets  'process each basket
        arr = dictBaskets(b)
        lb = LBound(arr)
        ub = UBound(arr)
        For i = lb To ub
            prodNum = dictUniqueProd(arr(i))
            prodCounts(prodNum) = prodCounts(prodNum) + 1 'increment count for this product
            For i2 = lb To ub
                If i2 <> i Then
                    prodNum2 = dictUniqueProd(arr(i2))
                    results(prodNum, prodNum2) = results(prodNum, prodNum2) + 1
                End If
            Next i2
        Next i
    Next b
    
    'convert co-occurence to % co-occurence (fraction of total unique purchases of product)
    For i = 1 To prodCount         'loop over each product
        tot = prodCounts(i)        'total for product i
        For i2 = 1 To prodCount    'loop over all other products
            If i2 <> i Then
                n = results(i, i2)
                If Len(n) > 0 Then
                    results(i, i2) = Round(100 * (n / tot), 0)
                End If
            End If
        Next i2
    Next i
    Debug.Print "Completed counts", Timer - t
    
    'show the results
    DisplayResults cTL, dictUniqueProd.Keys, prodCounts, results
    Debug.Print "Completed display", Timer - t
    
End Sub

'Process the data to get (as ByRef parameters):
'   (1) a dictionary of ticket Id vs.(array of unique ticket products)
'   (2) A dict of unique product names and indexes
Sub ProcessData(data, ByRef dictBaskets As Object, ByRef dictUniqueProd As Object)
    Dim r As Long, tick As String, prod As String, tmp
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        tick = data(r, 1)
        prod = data(r, 2)
        If Len(tick) > 0 And Len(prod) > 0 Then
            If Not dictUniqueProd.Exists(prod) Then 'collecting all unique products...
                dictUniqueProd.Add prod, dictUniqueProd.count + 1
            End If
            
            If Not dictBaskets.Exists(tick) Then 'new ticket/basket?
                dictBaskets.Add tick, Array(prod)
            Else
                tmp = dictBaskets(tick)
                'if prod wasn't already present, update the array in the dict
                If AddToUniqueArray(tmp, prod) Then dictBaskets(tick) = tmp
            End If      'new basket
        End If          'have both ticket and product
    Next r
End Sub

'Display the results starting at cell `rngTL`
Sub DisplayResults(rngTL As Range, arrProducts, arrProdTotals, results As Variant)
    Dim numProds As Long
    numProds = 1 + (UBound(arrProducts) - LBound(arrProducts))
    rngTL.Resize(numProds + 50, numProds + 50).Clear 'clear the results area
    rngTL.Value = "Totals"
    rngTL.offset(0, 1).Value = "Product"
    rngTL.offset(0, 2).Resize(1, numProds).Value = arrProducts
    rngTL.offset(1, 1).Resize(numProds, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrProducts)
    rngTL.offset(1, 0).Resize(numProds, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrProdTotals)
    rngTL.offset(1, 2).Resize(numProds, numProds).Value = results
End Sub

'Utility function: return a case-insensitive scripting dictionary
Function GetDict() As Object
    Set GetDict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    GetDict.CompareMode = 1 'case-insensitive
End Function

'Add value `v` to array `arr` if not already present
'Return True if the value was added
Function AddToUniqueArray(ByRef arr, v As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, ub As Long
    ub = UBound(arr)
    For i = LBound(arr) To ub 'check value not already present
        If StrComp(arr(i), v, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then Exit Function
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve arr(ub + 1) 'resize and add the new value
    arr(ub + 1) = v
    AddToUniqueArray = True
End Function

'########### end of analysis section

'generate some sample data
Sub GenData()
    Const NUM_BASKETS As Long = 1000
    Const NUM_PRODUCTS As Long = 300
    Const MAX_PER_BASKET As Long = 12 'must be < NUM_PRODUCTS (baskets have unique products only)
    
    Dim tick As String, t As Long, nItems As Long, n As Long, products As Collection, pnum As Long, prod As String
    Dim rw As Range, fmt As String
    fmt = String(Len(CStr(NUM_BASKETS)), "0") 'format for ticket/basket id suffix
    Set rw = ActiveSheet.Rows(2)
    For t = 1 To NUM_BASKETS
        Set products = AllProducts(NUM_PRODUCTS)
        tick = "TICK_" & Format(t, fmt)
        nItems = Application.RandBetween(1, MAX_PER_BASKET) '# of items in this basket
        
        For n = 1 To nItems
            pnum = Application.RandBetween(1, products.count)
            prod = products(pnum)
            products.Remove pnum 'remove the chosen item
            rw.Cells(1).Resize(1, 3) = Array(tick, prod, 1)
            Set rw = rw.offset(1)
        Next n
    Next t
End Sub

'return a collection of product names for creating a dummy dataset
Function AllProducts(numberOfProducts As Long) As Collection
    Dim n As Long, fmt As String
    fmt = String(Len(CStr(numberOfProducts)), "0") 'for formatting the suffix
    Set AllProducts = New Collection
    For n = 1 To numberOfProducts
        AllProducts.Add "Prod" & Format(n, fmt)
    Next n
End Function


Here's my worksheet showing sample data and the table summary (with color scale CF added)

Any real-world use case is going to have a much larger number of possible products, so your co-occurrence numbers will likely be much smaller, but it should give you some ideas about how to do this type of analysis.
